# SQL order by two different (possibly null) columns

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have a table with three columns; the first column contains IDs and the other two columns contain dates (where at most one is null, but I don't think this should affect anything). How would I go about ordering the IDs based on which date is larger? I've tried

```
ORDER BY CASE
WHEN date1 > date2 THEN date1
ELSE date2
END
```

but this didn't work. Can anyone help me? Also, all of the similar problems that I've seen others post have it so that the query sorts the results based on the first column, *and then if the first column is null*, the second column. Would I first have to define every single null value? I'm creating this table by a full outer join, so that would be an entirely different question to ask, so hopefully it can be done with null values.

Comment: Your `CASE` expression looks fine to me, except in that it doesn't support the case where `date2` is null; to support that as well, you'd want to write (say) `ORDER BY CASE WHEN date1 > date2 OR date2 IS NULL THEN date1 ELSE date2 END`. But you say that it "didn't work". Can you be more specific? For example, can you post actual data that fail to be ordered correctly?

Comment: Gabe, what database will be running the query?

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought they all worked the same. But I'm using Oracle. I don't know if that's specific enough for you guys though. :S

Comment: But it did seem that the problem was that the null values were doing something they shouldn't. I thought that null values were ignored, except in aggregations, but it seems like I read my notes wrong. :S

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe your problem is related to the comparison failing when either column is NULL.  So, you probably need:

```
 ORDER BY CASE
          WHEN date1 IS NULL THEN date2
          WHEN date2 IS NULL THEN date1
          WHEN date1 > date2 THEN date1
          ELSE                    date2
          END
```

Answer (score -2):

Try...

```
SELECT MAX(date1,date2) date FROM table ORDER BY date;
```

Comment: Yeah, but you can't really do it in Standard SQL without somehow joining the table onto itself on date1 != null, then join again on date2 != null, but give both the same ALIAS which has undefined behaviour.

Comment: (I've deleted my earlier comments, to replace them with one that's more clear.) I don't think any DBMS supports that use of `MAX`; maybe you're thinking of `GREATEST`? But anyway, there's really no need for this approach; these expressions can go in the `ORDER BY` clause just fine.

Comment: They could, but aliasing it as it's own column allows the date to also be retrieved. Extra, free functionality.

Comment: -1, sorry. You're giving nonsensical justifications for a broken query that doesn't do what the OP wants and does do things the OP hasn't asked for. If you don't know how to do something, you really don't need to just make up an answer.

Comment: You are right in that I meant GREATEST. However, knowing the chosen date would probably have been his next question or problem.